# Animal Named After Breasts

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry, limerick

I can be some famous duets,
an animal named 'cause of breasts,
a cute little toy,
by stagehands employed,
or sexennial safety threats.

**Who am I?**

Comment: @humn it is actually the indentation in the tooth that forms a mold of a breast, not that the tooth itself looks like a breast.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is:

> Dolly

I can be some famous duets

> <s>Dolly Parton, the singer. "Islands in the Stream" is one famous duet of hers.</s> [The Dolly Suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolly_(Faur%C3%A9)) A piano piece for 4 hands.

an animal named after breasts

> Dolly the sheep was named after Dolly Parton. ["Dolly is derived from a mammary gland cell and we couldn’t think of a more impressive pair of glands than Dolly Parton’s."](http://news.bbc.co.uk/onthisday/hi/dates/stories/february/22/newsid_4245000/4245877.stm)

a cute little toy

> A dolly.

by stagehands employed

> a dolly is used to move things around.

or sexennial safety threats

> Suggested by [Tom](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19547/tom) in comments  [Tropical Storm Dolly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_Storm_Dolly) has hit in 1996, 2002, 2008, and 2014.  Also, Tom points out that Storm Name Lists run on a six year cycle.

Comment: I mean, this is probably the right answer, but that's still not an accurate way to put that. It was named after *a person*, and **a person is different than breasts**

Comment: I see what you mean, but breasts are involved. More correct would be "An animal named because of breasts"

Comment: Yeah, that would be a much more accurate way of putting it, and also *significantly different*

Comment: Searching for "six years dolly" comes up with the sheep having passed away at six years old and also a Dolly Parton affair. :|

Comment: I've been doing the same.  Nothing I find really matches either.

Comment: Not to mention, the animal association is strengthened by artificiality at both ends

Comment: The "six years dolly" could be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_Storm_Dolly which hit in 1996, 2002, 2008, 2014 (and some six year intervals before that)

Comment: Fixed.  NOTE:  the [Space] Optional text here doesn't work.

Comment: I'm just finding out that  Atlantic Tropical Storm lists are used in rotation and re-cycled every six years (except if they are very costly and retired) so it is a sexennial safety threat http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/aboutnames.shtml

Comment: On the plus side, we probably all know more about the blue footed booby and the Eurasian blue tit than we did before.

Answer (score 10):

My answer is

> Possum

This is because

> It can be the name of a duet named ["Tonight I'm Playin' Possum"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FAJFLYG). Its name is similar to another word for breasts, which is bosom. It can be a [cute stuffed toy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006V7H86). The sexennial safety threat might be related to the average lifespan of a Victoria Possum, which is about 6-7 years.

Additional details after a comment on the subject:

> After a quick Google search, I found out that [Will Possum](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Will_Possum) is the stagehand at the town talent show in *Emmet Otter's Jug Band Christmas*.

Comment: I can't believe this. It's like _Emmet Otter's Jug-Band Christmas_ follows me everywhere; I cannot escape its reach. This is not the intended answer, sorry.

Comment: @Will I had never even heard of it before six months ago, but it's come up six separate times since then.

Comment: This answer is sheer genius, and deserves all the upvotes.